# Display Column Values for last record only in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi Iam having table like below,

```
Name RN  AGE
  A   1   21
  B   2   22
  C   3   23
```

I want to display age for last record only remaining column value as empty like below,

```
Name RN   AGE
  A   1   
  B   2   
  C   3   23
```

Comment: Can you clarify: what is RN? What is your primary key? When you say “last record”, in what order. If you can answer these, then the solution is quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *window function*

```
SELECT *,
         (CASE WHEN MAX(AGE) OVER () = AGE THEN CAST(AGE AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE '' END) AGE1
FROM table
```

You could also use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT *, 
         (CASE WHEN t.AGE <> c.MAXAGE THEN '' ELSE CAST(t.AGE AS VARCHAR(10)) END) AGE1
FROM table t CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(AGE) AS MAXAGE FROM table) c
```

This assumes last records in terms of *AGE* else you would need to *RN/Name* column to be aggregate and use them.